# jQuery AJAX for many generated divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

In a JSP, I have a number of similar divs (I don't know how many, they are generated based on some database value) with ids like event1, event2, etc.

Let's consider the div with id event1.
In this div, there is a button which has id foll1. On click of this button, I want to send an AJAX request to a servlet named "Follow" which will toggle the text in the button (text can be "Follow" or "Unfollow"). The AJAX request should send the value of an attribute with id=name1.

Comment: You should look at the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ page. lots of good examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Below code is for basic understanding, You may need to change as per you need, basically when user click it will check the text of the button and will call ajax with either true or false (follow/unfollow), on getting success response it will toggle text.

```
$("button").click(function(){

    var Invoker = this;

    if($(this.val() == "Unfollow"))
    {
        $.post("{Your Url}", { "follow" : false }, function(flag){
            if(flag == true) $(Invoker).val("Follow");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $.post("{Your Url}", { "follow" : true }, function(flag){
            if(flag == true) $(Invoker).val("Unfollow");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button class="js-addName" type="button" data-id="name1">Follow</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('button.js-addName').click(function(){
    // set your vars
    var theButton = $(this),
    theName = theButton.data('id');

    // ajax, and then use the promise
    $.post( "yourfile.jsp", { id: theName } ).done(function() { 
      $theButton.text($theButton.text() === "Follow" ? "Unfollow" : "Follow");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But my problem is how do I add this function to EVERY button?

Comment: Also, I don't want to send the id of the button, I want to send the id of another attribute in the div (a sibling of the button)